# cool open source projects on concurrent space?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I am looking for cool open source projects in the concurrent programming space in C and C++ which require active developer contribution. I am domain neutral, but would appreciate something more in the maths/statistics related areas. Any heads up people?

Comment: i think you would better off searching sourceforge.net instead to find the answer to this kind of question.

Comment: Yep, i think too, searching on sf.net and launchpad.net would be more resultative.

Comment: Better go to freshmeat.net, it is more complete directory than these project hosters.

Answer (score 1):

### Boost C++ Libraries collection

I would suggest taking a look at the [boost C++ library collection](http://www.boost.org/). There are several interesting libraries that deal with concurrent processing, and working on those libraries will drastically improve your own general and cross platform c++ programming skills. Some of their [libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/) are related to concurrency. The nice thing about boost is that is widely distributed, and is the source of many changes present in the C++0x update to the C++ standard so every contribution can have a huge impact.

**Accepted Concurrency Libraries**
 - [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) - Shared memory, memory mapped files, process-shared mutexes, condition variables, containers and allocators.
 - [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread.html) - Portable C++ multi-threading.
 - [Boost.MPI](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/mpi.html) - Message Passing Interface library, for use in distributed-memory parallel application programming.

**Accepted Math Libraries**
 - [Boost.Graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html) - The BGL graph interface and graph components are generic, in the same sense as the the Standard Template Library (STL).
 - [Boost.Math](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/index.html) - A wide selection of univariate statistical distributions and functions that operate on them.
 - [Boost.uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) - uBLAS provides matrix and vector classes as well as basic linear algebra routines. Several dense, packed and sparse storage schemes are supported.

**Libraries in Development**
 - [Libraries Under Construction](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/LibrariesUnderConstruction) - A list of libraries currently under development, many of which are concurrency and/or math related.
 - [Review Schedule](http://www.boost.org/community/review_schedule.html) - Gives you an overview of the development status of many of the libraries.